# Dart : Convert List to Stream<List>?

Tags: dart

I have a list. How to convert it to Stream ?

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> lst = [{"name": "Rob","id" : "1"}, {"name" : "Emily", "id" : "2"},{"name": "Bob","id" : "3"}];
```

My goal is when ever there is a add or delete in `lst` stream must listen and react to it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may want to use an [ObservableList](https://pub.dev/documentation/observable/latest/observable/ObservableList-class.html) as your list and it's member [changes](https://pub.dev/documentation/observable/latest/observable/Observable/changes.html) as your Stream.

Comment: Could you provide me a sample code ? I never used those @nvoigt

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28373786)

Comment: @CameronLittle Please look closely at what "Link-only" means. It means once the link goes dead, the answer is worthless. Should the two links in this answer go dead, the answer is just as valid as before, you'd just have to google the new link to the documentation yourself.